# A python problem: is there any way to return a new string that ask for remove a certain part?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Given a string, if the string "app" appears starting at index 1, return a string where that "app" has been deleted. Otherwise, return the string unchanged.

```
oApp('hello') → 'hello'
oApp('aapppotato') → 'apotato'
oApp('appmello') → 'appmello'

below is what I have until now...

    def oApp(string):
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[1] == "app":
                return string[0] + [3:]
            else:
                return string
```

Comment: could you show us your work until now? please consider to look [example]

Comment: Do you mean index 1 with zero based? Just asking to be sure

Comment: from index 1, but not include

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
oApp = lambda x: x[0]+x[4:] if x[1:].startswith('app') else x

assert oApp('hello') == 'hello'
assert oApp('aapppotato') == 'apotato'
assert oApp('appmello') == 'appmello'
```

Those assertion will not raise some errors, therefore it is working as intended.

Comment: hi, (sorry...I did not understand your code) I added something just now.. could you help me have a look? thank you

Comment: @Kuanlin Lai Hi, welcome to SO! I updated my answer. Take a look at lambdas to learn more about that topic, if something is not clear. They are a really powerful feature. Remember to accept this answer (the tick on the side of it) if it solves your problem.